# How to enable the inline assembly IntelliSense for Solidity on VSCode

Tags: solidity, assembly, ide

I have installed the solidity v0.0.125 extension from VSCode marketplace, but it seems doesn't support the inline assembly snippets by default. How to enable the feature or I need install more extentions?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The language used for inline assembly in Solidity is called [Yul](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#yul) and it is documented in its own section.

`vscode-solidity` does not support it, yet.

There is an extension with Yul support: [mjobuda.vscode-fe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjobuda.vscode-fe)

Based on: [Fe](https://github.com/ethereum/fe#getting-started)

Targeting Yul: [Reference](https://snakecharmers.ethereum.org/fe-a-new-language-for-the-ethereum-ecosystem/#:%7E:text=Targeting%20Yul,Ethereum%20Roadmap%20post.)

However installing `mjobuda.vscode-fe` along with `vscode-solidity` - intellisense for Yul is still not present. This is probably related to the extensions clashing on some level.

Reference: [Similar issue with different language](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5310#issuecomment-615541098)

I've opened an issue on the `vscode-solidity` repository with respect to intellisense for inline assembly: https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity/issues/275

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue to official.